# How to check null value in json?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Below is my JSON

```
{
  "mname":
   [
     {
       "Mname":"abc",
       "pname":[],
       "rewards":null
     }
   ]
}
```

How to check the reward array contains a null value?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [Stack Overflow: How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [Jon Skeet's Question Checklist](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist.aspx) to find out how to ask a good question that will generate good useful, answers.

Comment: Your json is a bit wrong, missing some curly brackets. Try to evaluate it first.

Comment: Use http://jsonlint.com/ to validate the JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code ,

```
    var data = {
         "mname": [
             {
                "Mname": "abc",
                "pname": [],
                "rewards": null
             }
          ]
     }

     $.each( data.mname , function( key, value ) {
         if(value.rewards == null || value.rewards == undefined){
                 // Add your codes/logic
         }
     });
```

Comment: Good answer! Can use `===` as well to speedup the execution. Read more here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/does-it-matter-which-equals-operator-vs-i-use-in-javascript-comparisons

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var data = {
  "mname":
   [
     {
       "Mname":"abc",
       "pname":[],
       "rewards":null
     }
   ]
}

if(data.mname[0].rewards == null || data.mname[0].rewards == undefined){


}
```